# Is it possible to redirect all url in my index page even if the file exist in the directory?

Tags: php, routes, redirect

I want to redirect all my website url to my index page which i have done by using .htaccess file , but if i place a file in my directory suppose a.php and open this page by direct url it doesn't redirect to index can anyone help

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove that `RewriteCond` line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . index.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Your 2nd line tells Apache that there is a condition for following rule: It must not be a file (note that `!-f` at the end of line).

Comment: Thank You Sir but by removing this the images in my website also get removed

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp)$` to exclude images.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `RewriteCond` line. :D
Your current condition checks if client requested to a non-exists file, then forward the request to the `index.php` file. Just not check anything, that's the key.

Comment: Thank you sir but by removing this the images in my website also get removed

Comment: You'll need to modify your cond: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index\.php|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif)$ [NC]` If you need to exclude any file extension, just add it like `|\.<ext>` before the `)$` chars.